# Input form provides File - how to I upload it to Azure Blob storage using Vue?

Tags: vue.js, azure-storage, fileapi

I'm clearly missing something here so forgive me - all examples seem to involve express and I don't have express in my setup. I am using Vue.js.

Ultimately, want my client-side Vue app to be able to upload any file to azure blob storage.

I have the file(File api) from my Vue form. However, it does not provide a path (I believe this is for security reasons). The Azure docs have this snippet example:

```
const uploadLocalFile = async (containerName, filePath) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const fullPath = path.resolve(filePath);
        const blobName = path.basename(filePath);
        blobService.createBlockBlobFromLocalFile(containerName, blobName, fullPath, err => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve({ message: `Local file "${filePath}" is uploaded` });
            }
        });
    });
};
```

Is this not the api I should be using? What should I be doing to upload any type of blob to blob storage?

- UPDATE

Following @Adam Smith-MSFT comments below I have tried the vue-azure-storage-upload but can't seem to get the files up to azure.

```
startUpload () {
            if (!this.files || !this.baseUrl) {
                window.alert('Provide proper data first!')
            } else {
                this.files.forEach((file:File) => {
                    this.$azureUpload({
                        baseUrl: this.baseUrl + file.name,
                        sasToken: this.sasToken,
                        file: file,
                        progress: this.onProgress,
                        complete: this.onComplete,
                        error: this.onError
                        // blockSize
                    })
                })  
            }   
        },
```

According to the console the response.data is undefined and when the onError method fires, that too gives me an undefined event.

Comment: Are you using their [SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-js)?

Comment: yes, the azure-storage SDK

Answer (score 1):

I'd highly recommend checking the following tutorial: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-azure-blob-upload
The author used a specific npm package to upload blobs(you can using file service) to upload objects:

```
npm i --save vue-azure-blob-upload
```

I'd also recommend checking the Storage JS documentation: https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-js/tree/master/file , it provides specific examples related to Azure File Storage as well.

Comment: Thank you. I will look into this and update if/when I get it working.

Comment: Sure let me know if you need any help.

Comment: I have followed the scant doc for vue-azure-blob-upload and am getting an error with an undefined response from azure to my request. I have updated my original question

Comment: ultimately got this working. Used the above-mentioned package but had to specify the x-ms-version date in the header.